# My internet connection became noticeably slower after downgrading from 20.04 to 18.04 MATE

Tags: networking, internet, mate

A couple of days ago I had problems with my new installed WiFi driver in Ubuntu 20.04. I couldn't solve it so I downgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 (MATE because I missed 16.04's feel)

This solved my driver problem, but for some reason its connection speed is slower than 20.04. I know MATE uses different configurations, any possibility it also causes my speed to slow down? Any explaining is appreciated

Comment: Downgrade isn't possible, at least not with a lot of painstaking work.  It can also be extremely messy to switch desktop environments on an installed system. If you did these things I'd be surprised that this is the only problem.  Also, support for Ubuntu MATE 18.04 has ended.  LTS Ubuntu flavors are supported three years from the release. I suggest that you instead install Ubuntu MATE 20.04 cleanly.  MATE doesn't match 16.04's "feel". MATE is a fork of GNOME 2.  GNOME 2 hasn't been used by Ubuntu since versions 10.04/10.10

Comment: @Nmath I should've been more clear. By downgrade I meant I erased disk and installed fresh. Also by 16.04's feel I simply meant the Mutiny dock. I didn't know MATE 18.04's support ended, I thought it was similar to main Ubuntu, 5 years. Well, thank you nonetheless, I will upgrade to 20.04 MATE

Comment: Since this is already a clean installation, a clean install of Ubuntu MATE 20.04 would probably be more prudent. It would be faster and cleaner